# Force UITableView to dump all reusable cells

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView where I have the backgroud color set via

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
if ((indexPath.row % 2) == 0)
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
else
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

cell.backgroundView = myView;
[myView release];
```

The problem I find is that when I edit a table (via setEditing:YES...) some cells of the same color invariable are next to each other. How do I force UITableView to fully redraw. reloadData is not doing a great job.

Is there are deep-cleaning redraw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue before so I'll share with you how I solved it:

You can use a boolean flag (say it's called `needsRefresh`) to control the behavior of cell creation in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

An example:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueResuableCellWithIdentifier:SOME_ID];
    if(!cell || needsRefresh) {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] init....] autorelease];
    }
    //.....
    return cell;
}
```

So, when you need a hard reload, set the `needsRefresh` flag to `YES`. Simple as a pimple.

Comment: It works. My program has a very complicated cell structure, so I had missed the right spot to apply your suggestion. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: will this not cause any memory leak?

Comment: I'm wondering where do you set the needsRefresh flag back to NO after performing all the required reloads... Should this solution be complimented by some sort of cell tracking that sets it back to false after updating all the visible cells?

Comment: This is not true for custom cells created from NIB - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197816/force-uitableview-to-dump-all-reusable-cells

Comment: @JacobRelkin thanks for such a wonderful answer i am struggling with this issue for last one day....thanks again

Comment: @luvieere your question is right when we have to set needsRefresh flag back to NO... i have implemented counter for this once counter reaches to my data source array's count i have set needsRefresh flag back to NO. that's it...

Comment: @PRJ Users may scroll down, then up, then down again, then up once more and only at the end get to the bottom of the data source. As such , the refresh count is of no relevance, as the very same cell would be refreshed multiple times; you need to maintain a persistent state flag, IsRefreshed, associated to each cell's data.

Comment: This answers the OP's question, but the **title** of the question -- how do you get a table to dump all queued stuff -- is still a mystery to me. Will a `UITableView` dump all queued cells when... it has no superview? When it deallocs?

Answer (score 3):

For me the accepted answer didn't really work since I had no idea when to set the needsRefresh back to YES.

What worked for me was:

```
 - (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueResuableCellWithIdentifier:customCellIdentifier];
    if(nil == cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:customCellIdentifier];
    }
    //.....
    return cell;
}
```

And then you change the customCellIdentifier value whenever you need to. This way the cells are also still reusable if you switch back to the original cell identifier.

Comment: I've put a slightly extended version of this below.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted method seems dirty, it just makes a bunch of new cells that are stored along with the bad ones. Here are a couple of solutions depending on your situation:

1.
first, for the situation described in the question you should not dump your cells and create new views on every cycle. You need to tag your view and then get it back when from the cell when you get a reuse cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueResuableCellWithIdentifier:SOME_ID];
    if(!cell) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

         UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];    
        cell.backgroundView = myView;

        [myView setTag:5]; //<------
    }

    UIView *myView =  [cell viewWithTag:5];  //<------
    if ((indexPath.row % 2) == 0)
        myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    else
        myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return cell;
}

//then just reload the tableview.
```

2.
...or even better, why not just use the cell backgrouncolor and update that without creating a view.

3.
A sure way to really clear out old cached cells it to simply recreate the UITableView object.

4.
In most cases you dont need to destroy these cells, just keep track of your elements and update them after getting the reusable cell.You can tag all your elements, keep a array reference to them, find them thought the view hierarchy... Im sure theres a bunch of other ways.

5.
heres a one liner to directly purge all cells, although not best practice to mess with the internals of objects like this as they might change in future versions:

```
[(NSMutableDictionary*)[tableview valueForKey:@"_reusableTableCells" ] removeAllObjects];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding a refresh variable to the table datasource. I used a dictionary for each cell, but there's an extra key called @"refresh":@"1", indicating the cell needs refreshing. Once it's updated, I set that key's value to @"0". So whenever the table is reloaded, make sure the key goes back to @"0" again.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define TABLE_VIEW_CELL_DEFAULT_ID @"cellIdentifier"
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tableViewCellIdentifier;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger tableViewCellIdentifierCount;

// By using a different cell identifier, this effectively flushes the cell 
// cache because the old cells will no longer be used.
- (void) flushTableViewCellCache
{
    self.tableViewCellIdentifierCount++;
    self.tableViewCellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i", TABLE_VIEW_CELL_DEFAULT_ID, self.tableViewCellIdentifierCount];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:self.tableViewCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:self.tableViewCellIdentifier];
    }

    // rest of method...
}
```